Can't See the CVV field on Apple Developer Program Payment Form
I'm trying to complete my Apple Developer Program Order.
I'm unable to enter the CVV field of my VISA Card.
There are no field for this. You can see the screenshot.
I can just enter the card number.
So that cause my payment failed every time I try.
I try to complete my apple developper program order with my visa card.
I expected to be able to enter both the VISA card number and the CVV code for order completion.
Apple Developer Program Order Form Snapshot
